# Get textfield value on Button Click in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am developing IOS Application.to get textfield value on button click in TableViewCell. i can get index of button and pass to TableViewCell and than cell pass to textfield.and getting text from textfield to get (Null) text. But is problem. Please help thanks in advance.

```
//Tableviewcell create textfield

_quantity = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(770.0f, 10.0f,80.0f, 30.0f)];
[_quantity setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
_quantity.delegate =self;
[_quantity.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[_quantity.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
_quantity.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_quantity.tag = indexPath.row;
_quantity.text = obj.productQuantity;
_quantity.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[_quantity setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[cell addSubview:_quantity];

_quantitySave = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(770.0f, 45.0f,80.0f, 20.0f)];
_quantitySave.tag = indexPath.row;
[_quantitySave.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
[_quantitySave.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[_quantitySave.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
_quantitySave.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[_quantitySave setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_quantitySave addTarget:self action:@selector(saveQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cell addSubview:_quantitySave];

-(IBAction)saveQuantity:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSInteger index = button.tag;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:index];
    NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
}
```

Comment: You did not set the button tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` delegate. There should be `yourButton.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: yes i am set button index

Comment: your button is in every cell? or you have only one button?

Comment: button or Textfield is on every Cell

Answer (score 1):

You are adding tag in your `UITextField` as `_quantity.tag = indexPath.row;` and getting index from `button.tag` which you didn't set yet. You should add `tag` in your button.

```
_quantity = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(770.0f, 10.0f,80.0f, 30.0f)];
    [_quantity setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
    _quantity.delegate =self;
    [_quantity.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [_quantity.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    _quantity.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    //_quantity.tag = indexPath.row;
    yourButtonObject.tag = indexPath.row
    _quantity.text = obj.productQuantity;
    _quantity.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [_quantity setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [cell addSubview:_quantity];


-(IBAction)saveQuantity:(id)sender{
 UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
 NSInteger index = button.tag;

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:index];
 NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
```

Comment: Not working its again (null)..One more problem is that when scroll tableview change value of each textfield of tableview cell.

Comment: Why you are not using custom `UITableViewCell` class and a `UITextField` and `UIButton` on it. You are allocating `UITextField` every time cell dequeues which creating problem here.

Answer (score 0):

To create a editable `UITableViewCell` in more elegant way, check following image this will give you all the code needed in order to create a TableView Cell which respond to done action and print selected cell's textfield's text.

[image]

I will add code once I have figured why my git account is not working.